# Convert to lower case and upper case , inside class with method using Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, methods

Create a Str class with methods to:

Add lower method to convert a string to lower case.

```
Str.lower('EAT') // eat
```

Add upper method to convert a string to upper case.

```
Str.upper('today') // TODAY
```

I try with code below , but did not work

```
class Str {
    constructor(lower,upper) {
        this.lower = lower.toLoweCase(); 
        this.upper = upper.toUpperCase();
    }
}

Str.lower('HALO');
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'but did not work', please? Just for future reference is all. @Isaac managed to find a misspelling in your `toLowerCase()` function call; you're missing an `r`.

Comment: `class Str { static lower(s) { return s.toLowerCase(); } static upper(s) { return s.toUpperCase(); } }` doing other people's homework ftw.

Comment: Honestly most of the time are quite difficult to grab a new concept if you're a self learner. It's really unfair to bash anyone for posting `easy` question. It is `easy` only because you're no longer a amateur. Stackoverflow is to share love among community for my best understanding

Comment: @ASDFGerte: Hope you're not offended as I'm a self-learner in `JS` and often feeling frustrated over so many new concept and couldn't grab  them. `Stackoverflow` is one of the very few place I can rely on

Comment: @Isaac It's pretty hard to "offend" me over the internet without knowing any personal details about me. When questions are too "fundamental" ("easy", if you so wish), i just often think it would be better to read a longer tutorial/book about the general subject. Sure, it takes a whole lot longer than answering the immediate problem, but will be more beneficial on the long run. For myself, i like solving such questions (as long as they are well defined like this one). Sometimes i post my answer. If it takes me time or i even make a mistake (which happens), i will learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working

```
class Str {
  constructor(lower,upper) {
    this.lower = lower.toLowerCase(); 
    this.upper = upper.toUpperCase();
  }
}

let x = new Str('HALO','what');
x.lower; //halo
```

Your code `this.lower = lower.toLowerCase();` is not creating a function. It is simply declaring a variable that holds the value of `lower.toLowerCase()`. Instead you should try the following

```
class Str {
  constructor(lower,upper) {
    this.lowerName = lower.toLowerCase(); 
    this.upperName = upper.toUpperCase();
  }

  lower(input) {
    return input.toLowerCase();
  }
}

let y = Str.prototype.lower('WHAT'); //what
```

Unless you're creating an instance of `Str`, else invoking the function `lower` like above because the function sits inside `prototype` of `class`/`object`. You can picture it as function borrowing from `Str` class

Another way you can try as below:

```
class Str {
  constructor(lower = "",upper="") {
    this.lowerName = lower.toLowerCase(); 
    this.upperName = upper.toUpperCase();
  }

  lower(input) {
    return input.toLowerCase();
  }
}
let strInstance = new Str();
console.log(strInstance.lower('WHY'));
```

Now the above code lets you create an instance of `Str` and invoke the function

Comment: Gimme a short moment for it

Comment: @VicJordan: Tried my best for the explanation, hope I understand the concept correctly as well as I'm also a newbie